# Combine indexof and Subtring

Tags: java, string

I only want to retrieve the last name with the indexof and subtring

Let me show you the code :

```
public class ssq {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String chaine = "Durand;Marcel;2 523.5";`
```

I only want to retrieve Durand.

I tried this

```
System.out.println(chaine.indexOf(";"),chaine.substring(0,6));
```

Comment: [Split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) on the semi-colon. Or use `indexOf` and `substring`. Ex: `chaine.substring(0, chaine.indexOf(';'))`

Comment: That is my problem i try to use an indexof and a subtring but it didn't work

Comment: Adding my comment from an "answer" below. Apologies for sounding harsh, but you cannot expect SO to do the assignments for you. Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html Then Ctrl+F. Then type indexOf or substring. Then find the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf(String substring)` method returns the position of the first occurrence of specified character(s) in the `chain` string which is `;`.

`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` Returns a new string that is a `substring` of the `chain` string.

```
System.out.println(chaine.substring(0, chaine.indexOf(";")));
```